# How to do a for loop over values read by a string stream in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, struct, stringstream

I have a program that is supposed to read an input file via string stream. The file contains student names, and test scores that I want to average. The file can contain any number of test scores for any number of students greater than 1 and less than 10.

If I am reading all the values in the file by string stream, how would I store each test score value as an integer where I can sum them? Here is the code I have so far, which I am not sure is even correct:

```
 string fname, lname, line;
 getline(cin, line);
 istringstream sin;
 sin.str(line);
 sin >> fname >> lname;
```

Is this the right way to parse through values? At the top, I declared a struct 'student' like this:

```
struct student {
  string first_name;
  string last_name;
  double avg_score;
} student1;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just use `cin >> fname >> lname;`?  It does the same thing.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you showed a bit more code and if you could point to the line where you dont know what to do. Please read about [mcve]

Comment: @NathanOliver: I think it's because a line can contain any number of scores; So I'd read in each line separately, too, as it more clearly expresses that each line is treated as a separate "record".

Answer (score 0):

If each line varies in the number of scores I'd tend to read in complete lines and parse them, one after the other. Thereby you can rely on the `>>`-operator to return `false` once no more score could be read in a line. So I think you are on the right way. See the following code demonstrating how to deal with the return values of `>>`:

```
int main() {

    ifstream f(DATAFILE);
    if(f) {
        string line;
        while (getline(f,line)) {
            string fname,lname;
            istringstream ss(line);
            if (ss >> fname >> lname) {
                double sum = 0;
                double value;
                int count = 0;
                while (ss >> value) {
                    sum += value;
                    count++;
                }
                cout << line << " gives average: " << sum/count << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Storing the values in a `struct` is straight forward (and left up to you :-)). In case you face troubles please ask.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store multiple data you typically need a so-called container class. Container classes can store an arbitrary number of data of the same type and provide methods to manage the container elements.

The standard container class in C++ is `std::vector`, so, for example, in your case you may define a container by

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<student> allStudents;
```

To add the data of `student1` you may do

```
allStudents.push_back(student1)
```

For anything else you better read a beginner's C++ text book, as working with container classes is a basic skill of a C++ programmer.